# Swift functions

Tags: ios, function, swift, println

I am learning Swift and I got problem with understanding how functions work.
Let's say I got a simple function:

```
func sayHello() {
  println("hello there")
}
```

And I can assign this function to variable or constant in that way:

```
var hello = sayHello
```

So now variable hello is type of function which can be written in that way:

```
var hello:() -> () = sayHello
```

And now I can run/execute (is it a proper wording?) sayHello function by typing:

```
hello()
```

which prints my output "hello there"

**The question is whats the difference between this:**

```
var hello1 = sayHello()
hello1 // it prints out hello there string
```

and that:

```
var hello2 = sayHello
hello2() // it prints out hello there string as well
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell,

`hello1` is the result of the execution of `sayHello`. But because your function does not return anything, its value will be a `Void`.

`hello2` on the other hand is a reference to the function `sayHello`. It is of type `() -> ()`. That's why you need to execute it (the trailing '()' in your example) to get the result.

This is what we call **[First Class Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)**. One of the characteristics is that functions can be passed around and used like a variable.